# GSPCA : Could not get descriptor

Tags: linux, drivers, kernel-modules, hardware, camera

I found a old webcam in store room. The Windows detect it as Creative GO mini but lacks a driver. I plugged it in my Manjaro hoping for Linux to revive it.The device is old and use **GSPCA** driver. It does have a driver, listed by [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/media/v4l-drivers/gspca-cardlist.html), and tries to load it. But there is a error to find the bus descriptor so I can't use it. It is listed in `lsusb` though. I am giving the verbose output.

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 041e:4007 Creative Technology, Ltd Go Mini
Device Descriptor:
bLength                18
bDescriptorType         1
bcdUSB               1.10
bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
bDeviceSubClass         0 
bDeviceProtocol         0 
bMaxPacketSize0         8
idVendor           0x041e Creative Technology, Ltd
idProduct          0x4007 Go Mini
bcdDevice            0.00
iManufacturer           1 (error)
iProduct                2 Creative WebCam Go Mini (LCDC)
iSerial                 0 
bNumConfigurations      1
Configuration Descriptor:
 bLength                 9
 bDescriptorType         2
 wTotalLength       0x0022
 bNumInterfaces          1
 bConfigurationValue     1
 iConfiguration          0 
 bmAttributes         0xa0
   (Bus Powered)
   Remote Wakeup
 MaxPower               70mA
 Interface Descriptor:
   bLength                 9
   bDescriptorType         4
   bInterfaceNumber        0
   bAlternateSetting       0
   bNumEndpoints           0
   bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
   bInterfaceSubClass      0 
   bInterfaceProtocol      0 
   iInterface              0 
 Interface Descriptor:
   bLength                 9
   bDescriptorType         4
   bInterfaceNumber        0
   bAlternateSetting       1
   bNumEndpoints           1
   bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
   bInterfaceSubClass      0 
   bInterfaceProtocol      0 
   iInterface              0 
   Endpoint Descriptor:
     bLength                 7
     bDescriptorType         5
     bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
     bmAttributes            2
       Transfer Type            Bulk
       Synch Type               None
       Usage Type               Data
     wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
     bInterval               0
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
(Bus Powered)
```

And here is the loaded modules for it.

```
gspca_stv0680          16384  0
gspca_main             32768  1 gspca_stv0680
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  2 gspca_main,uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  2 gspca_main,uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       57344  3 gspca_main,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              270336  4 gspca_main,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

And here goes the error message

```
[ 4271.175296] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 4271.838163] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=041e, idProduct=4007, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 4271.838170] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 4271.838173] usb 2-1: Product: Creative WebCam Go Mini (LCDC)
[ 4271.838176] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Creative Technology Ltd
[ 4241.263953] gspca_main: v2.14.0 registered
[ 4241.269868] gspca_main: stv0680-2.14.0 probing 041e:4007
[ 4242.328049] gspca_stv0680: Could not get descriptor 0100
[ 4242.330259] stv0680 2-1:1.0: last error: 0,  command = 0x8f
[ 4242.330283] stv0680: probe of 2-1:1.0 failed with error -5
[ 4242.330359] usbcore: registered new interface driver stv0680
```

Now what can I do??

Comment: you can buy a camera that works with linux

Comment: @jsotola Thank you but sorry , that doesn't  help. I have a built-in webcam , and that works. My point is to revive that camera, not to get a webcam. Anyway, that is supposed to work with Linux, it has driver and someone ran it and got in trouble while running it and I find people's writings in internet.